# Gas Exhausted error

Tags: rpc, transactions, gas, python

I am trying to use pytezos to perform a transaction on Tezos testnet.

I am receiving a 'Gas Exhausted' error although it is suppose to autofill.

Python code:

```
native_key = await Key.from_mnemonic(words, curve=b"sp")
    
# Get account info
bal = pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz').account(native_key.public_key_hash())  
    
print ("\nPK Hash: ", native_key.public_key_hash(), "\n")
print ("\nBalance: ", bal ["balance"], " mutez\n")
         
sourceAddr = native_key.public_key_hash()
targetAddr = "tz1VZGEWA3daTHj3tNvRf6SR3tSVrpWb2xN2"
targetAmt = Decimal('1.23')
print ("\nAmt: ", targetAmt, " tez\n")
    
tztx = pytezos.using(shell='https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz', key=native_key).transaction(source=sourceAddr, destination=targetAddr, amount=targetAmt).autofill().sign().inject()
```

Error:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://rpc.ghostnet.teztnets.xyz:443 "POST /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/scripts/run_operation HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:pytezos:<<<<< 200
{
    "contents": [
        {
            "kind": "transaction",
            "source": "tz2HBLPFd1wo7ebsm6P6y5M1hSUKgvXd8igV",
            "fee": "414",
            "counter": "11664705",
            "gas_limit": "1427",
            "storage_limit": "257",
            "amount": "1230000",
            "destination": "tz1VZGEWA3daTHj3tNvRf6SR3tSVrpWb2xN2",
            "metadata": {
                "balance_updates": [
                    {
                        "kind": "contract",
                        "contract": "tz2HBLPFd1wo7ebsm6P6y5M1hSUKgvXd8igV",
                        "change": "-414",
                        "origin": "block"
                    },
                    {
                        "kind": "accumulator",
                        "category": "block fees",
                        "change": "414",
                        "origin": "block"
                    }
                ],
                "operation_result": {
                    "status": "failed",
                    "errors": [
                        {
                            "kind": "temporary",
                            "id": "proto.013-PtJakart.gas_exhausted.operation"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "signature": "sigUHx32f9wesZ1n2BWpixXz4AQaZggEtchaQNHYGRCoWNAXx45WGW2ua3apUUUAGMLPwAU41QoaFCzVSL61VaessLg4YbbP"
}
```

Comment: This is most likely an outdated pytezos version, pls update to 3.6.1
If it says "No matching distribution found" then you probably have an old python version, you need at least 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an estimation bug on pytezos side, which only seems to happen for transactions without parameters.

Try the following:

```
<...>.transaction(
    destination=targetAddr,
    amount=targetAmt,
    gas_limit=1451, // Hard-coded gas_limit based on the latest transactions (not perfect, but should unlock you for now)
).send()
```